# Jquery Opens Multiple Dialog boxes in MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Jquery Opens Multiple Dialog boxes in MVC 4.0
In _layout file I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#tabs").tabs();
$("#dialog").dialog({
autoopen: false,
height: 600,
            width: 800
        });
    });
 </script>
```

and when I use an Ajax call using this:

```
success: function (data) {
                   $("#dialog").html(data);

                    }
```

it show a lot more 100 of dialog boxes and keeps opening until closed forcely,
but when I use only

```
success: function (data) {
                   alert(data);

                    }
```

it shows only 1 alert box containing data,
Please lead me to some Solution,

Comment: how many response u r getting back from the server after u make the ajax request?

Comment: It is returning me 50+ responses at least,
when I stop server then i counted, I am using MVC 4.0 .net

Comment: gotcha..that's why so many popups. What javascript 'alert' does is that it stop everything until u have hit 'Ok'. while with jquery dialog that wont happen. Try to return only one response back from controller and things will work normally for u. Jquery dialog is nothing but a div.

Comment: and try to use debugging tools like firebug and try to check the network tab and check for the GET and POST request and response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show()
{
$("#dialog").dialog({
autoopen: false,
height: 600,
width: 800
});
}
</script>

success: function (data) {
$("#dialog").html(data);
show();
}
```